# depends on both floor_generator ^1.2.0 and retrofit_generator ^4.0.1, version solving failed

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using retrofit_generator and floor_generator in my application.

```
retrofit_generator: ^4.0.1
floor_generator: ^1.2.0
```

When I am trying to run `flutter packages pub run build_runner build` getting this error:

```
Because no versions of retrofit_generator match >4.0.1 <5.0.0 and retrofit_generator 4.0.1 depends on analyzer ^3.0.0, re
trofit_generator ^4.0.1 requires analyzer ^3.0.0.
And because floor_generator >=1.2.0 depends on analyzer ^2.2.0, retrofit_generator ^4.0.1 is incompatible with floor_gene
rator >=1.2.0.
So, because my_flutter_app depends on both floor_generator ^1.2.0 and retrofit_generator ^4.0.1, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in my_flutter_app...
pub get failed (1; So, because my_flutter_app depends on both floor_generator ^1.2.0 and retrofit_generator ^4.0.1,
version solving failed.)
```

Also, tried to add `analyzer: ^3.0.0` in dev_dependencies then:

```
Because floor_generator >=1.2.0 depends on analyzer ^2.2.0 and my_flutter_app depends on analyzer ^3.0.0, floor_generator >=1.2.0 is forbidden.
So, because my_flutter_app depends on floor_generator ^1.2.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because my_flutter_app depends on floor_generator ^1.2.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

How can we use both without errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the `retrofit_generator` CHANGELOG, you will see there was a breaking change on version `4.0.0` making the library depend on version `3.0.0` but `floor_generator` hasn't been updated for the last 7 months and it depends on older version of `analyzer`.

Possible solution would be to downgrade `retrofit_generator` in a version prior to the breaking change, or wait till the publisher of `floor_generator` updates its dependencies.

Comment: Can you suggest what exact versions need to use?

Comment: The last version prior the breaking change is `3.0.1`, try that.

Answer (score 0):

They said on there github on issue:

> It looks like the current master already supports analyzer <5.0.0 but
> it's not on pub.dev yet because of a failed test because the pub
> command can't be found.
> check this link [the issue](https://github.com/trevorwang/retrofit.dart/issues/473)

so thanks for this at least now we can use the git url until you publish it on pub.dev .

use:

```
  retrofit_generator:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/trevorwang/retrofit.dart.git/
      ref: master
      path: generator
```

instead of

```
retrofit_generator: ^4.0.1
```